# Selecting no item from database returns 1, why?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have three small questions... I have this following query on mysql in my php...
it delivers me the value 0 after selecting, even there is no bla = $bla - it should deliver me no value, why it deliveres me 0?

second question: the result is 1 - why does the selection succeed, even there is no bla = $bla?

third question: how can I know the selection wasn't succeded due to no item was selected because the WHERE condition did not succeeded.

```
$stmt= $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM column WHERE bla = ?");
    $stmt-> bind_param("s", $bla);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt -> bind_result($id);

        echo $result;
```

Comment: `echo $id;` - not `$result`!

Comment: do $id contain the result if it succeeded or not?
so $id = 1, succeded. if 0 then not?

Comment: Ah, you want to know if the query succeeded or failed? Then you need to check `$stmt->execute()`, not necessarily the `bind_result()`

Comment: yes i tried it , but $stmt-execte() gives TRUE - even there is nothing to select to^^ do it return TRUE even it selects no value?

Comment: Yes it will. As long as the query is correct/not rejected, it will return true. If you want to find out if there have been 0 rows returned, use either [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) or deal with that in your `fetch()` (which is still missing in your code)

Comment: yeah $stmt->num_rows > 0 did it^^


ok... i did not know that it gives me positive result even it selected no item, because there were no item corresponding to the where clause :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code. `$result` is the result of the query execution. It is not the data from the SQL statement.

`execute` returns a boolean. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php